# How to increment a parameter in an Azure Data Factory Until Activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am accessing a RESTful API that pages results in groups of 50 using the HTTP connector.  The REST connector doesn't seem to support Client Certificates so I can't use the pagination in that.

I have a Pipeline Variable called `SkipIndex` that defaults to 0.  Inside the Until loop I have a Copy Data Activity that works (HTTP source to BLOB sink), then a Set Variable Activity that I am trying to get to increment this Variable.

```
{
    "name": "Add 50 to SkipIndex",
    "type": "SetVariable",
    "dependsOn": [
        {
            "activity": "Copy next to temp",
            "dependencyConditions": [
                "Succeeded"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "userProperties": [],
    "typeProperties": {
        "variableName": "SkipIndex",
        "value": {
            "value": "50++",
            "type": "Expression"
        }
    }
}
```

Everything I have tried results in errors such as "The expression contains self referencing variable. A variable cannot reference itself in the expression." and the one above with `50++` causes a sink error during debug.

How can I get the Until loop to increment this variable after it retrieves data?

Comment: Please vote for adding Client Certificate Authentication to the REST connector: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/5555b27e-f146-ec11-a819-0022484e8090

Comment: Please vote for adding an Increment activity: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/a479cced-f246-ec11-a819-0022484e8090

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Agree that REST Connector does supports pagination but does not for `Client Certificates` Authentication type.

For the idea of your `Until activity` scenario,i am tripped by the `can't self-reference a variable in an expression` limitation also. Maybe you could make a little trick on that: Add one more variable to persist the index number.

For example,i got 2 variables: `count` and `indexValue`

Until Activity:

[image]

Inside Until Activity:

[image]

V1:

[image]

V2:

[image]

BTW, no usage of `50++` in ADF.

Comment: @Graham Yes...agree that. Anyway,be a workaround so far.

Comment: I really appreciate this workaround!  Strange but creative.

Comment: I get : The function 'int' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target type