# Azure Data Factory : returns an array of dates from a specified range

Tags: date, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to returns an array of dates in data factory. But i just want the user to specify a date range with two parameters, startDate and endDate :

I want to return this array by specifying "12-08-2020" and "12-13-2020" in trigger :

```
["12-08-2020","12-09-2020","12-10-2020","12-12-2020","12-13-2020"]
```

Do did not find a simple way to do it yet.
One way i thought about would be :

- add a lookup activity on a date dimension,
- then add two filters to select only items greater than startDate and lower than endDate.

But this seems to be cumbersome and overkill. Is there a simpler way to do it ?

---

EDIT :

---

This answer seems to be relevant (i did not see it at first) : [Execute azure data factory foreach activity with start date and end date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448774/execute-azure-data-factory-foreach-activity-with-start-date-and-end-date)

Comment: Hi @GuillaumeLabs, I've updated my answer. I think use  lookup activity is easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think we can use **recursive query** in Lookup activity.
The pseudo code is as follows:
In sql we can use this query to get a table:

```sql
;with temp as 
(
    select CONVERT(varchar(100),'12-08-2020', 110) as dt
union all 
    select CONVERT(varchar(100), DATEADD(day,1,dt), 110) from temp
    where datediff(day,CONVERT(varchar(100), DATEADD(day,1,dt), 110),'12-13-2020')>=0
) select * from temp
```

The result is as follows:
[image]

So in ADF, I think we can use a Lookup sql query to return the result what you want.

According to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions), we only need to replace the parameters of the sql statement.

Next,I will use `'@{pipeline().parameters.startDate}'` to return a date string, note: There is a pair of single quotes outside.

1. I set two parameters as follows:
   [image]
2. Type the following code into a Lookup activity.

```sql
;with temp as 
(
    select CONVERT(varchar(100),'@{pipeline().parameters.startDate}', 110) as dt
union all 
    select CONVERT(varchar(100), DATEADD(day,1,dt), 110) from temp
    where datediff(day,CONVERT(varchar(100), DATEADD(day,1,dt), 110),'@{pipeline().parameters.endDate}')>=0
) select * from temp
```

Don't select **First row only**.
[image]

3. The debug result is as follows:
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

I had similar use case and ended up using **Until** with little changes.
Two parameters which takes two parameters *start_day* and *end_day*
[image]

Also have to introduce two variables for implementing counter logic. more details can be found at [how-to-increment-parameter-data-factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795937/how-to-increment-a-parameter-in-an-azure-data-factory-until-activity?rq=1)

and finally the expression in the untill block is

```
@less(int(adddays(pipeline().parameters.end_day, 0, 'yyyyMMdd')), int(adddays(pipeline().parameters.start_day, int(variables('counter')), 'yyyyMMdd')))
```

**final note** the *until* block executes when the expression returns **false** and loops out on **true**

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get something similar to work with a combination of derived column transformation using a `mapLoop()` function followed by a flatten transformation.

The derived column expression first calculates an array of dates in a single column.

`mapLoop(toInteger((To_Date - From_Date)/86400000)),toDate(addDays(From_Date,#index)))`

where 86400000 is the number of miliseconds in 24 hours

The flatten transformation uses this column to unroll the array into separate rows.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on bmaci's answer as I don't have the reputation, but it is the solution if you then want to then use your array to generate rows, one for each date in the array between startDate and endDate.   It just needs a couple of amendments to account for data types and syntax oddities in the factory:

1. Assuming startDate and endDate are date fields, make a Derived Column with the expression:

   mapLoop(({endDate}-{startDate})+1, toString(addDays({startDate}-1,#index)))

   This creates a string array from the startDate to the endDate, but accounts for the fact that the first index is 1 and not 0.  If you didn't include the -1 part in the addDays() function, the first item in the array would be startDate + 1 day, which is not what you want.

   Also, the toString() part is because the output of the mapLoop() function seems to be an array of strings only.  Even the official mapLoop() example of mapLoop(3, #index * 10) doesn't actually work because of this oddity.
2. Add a Flatten after the Derived Column.  "Unroll by" on your new array field and ensure you have all the input columns you want mapped correctly as you like.  This creates the vertical stack, one row per date,
3. Add another Derived Column to convert your new field from string to date, using the appropriate toDate() function