# How to get full filepath and to path them to foreach activity in Azure Synapse Analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I need to process all the data contained within ADLS Gen2.
The data is stored in parquet format, not in databases, and the folder structure looks like this.
[image: folda structure]

The process is the same for all files, but the processed files must be overwritten in the same location.
I intend to accomplish this in the following ways:

1. Get full filepath of all files using "Get Metadata" activity.
2. After passing the file paths one by one to the foreach activity, the files are processed one by one and stored in their original locations.

However, the Get Metadata activity could not successfully retrieve the file path because wildcards are not allowed in the source data set.
How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Is the schema for all the files same?

Comment: Yes, all files have the same schema.

Comment: combining all the file rows count, how many number of rows in total that you have?

Comment: There are about ten billion rows.

Answer (score 0):

**Get Meta data activity** won't give the full folder path even though you defined a wild card placeholder.

If you have less row count on overall, you can use copy activity addional column for file path and merge all files and save it in a temporary location. Later using lookup activity, get that column and you can get unique list using union of it. But lookup won't give the output for more than 5000 rows.

So, I tried the below approach to get all file paths in an array.

First, I have generated **array for folder paths(with dates)** using lookup activity SQL script.

If you want to avoid SQL database script, use **until activity** by initializing start date and end date to get the list of folder paths of dates.

First Go through your folder paths and identify the **start date** and **end date** for the folders. Give those values to parameters like this.

Here this is my folder structure:

```
inputdata
    year=2023
        month=04
            day=20
                File01.parquet
            day=21
                File01.parquet
                File02.parquet
            day=22
                File01.parquet
                File02.parquet
            day=23
                File01.parquet
                File02.parquet
            day=24
                File01.parquet
                File02.parquet
```

According to my folder structure `2023/04/20` and `2023/04/24` are start date and end date respectively.

[image]

I have used the below SLQ script from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65277680) by @**Joseph Xu** in lookup to get folder paths array.

```
;with dtable as 
(
    select CONVERT(varchar(100),'@{pipeline().parameters.folders_s_date}', 111) as mydate
union all 
    select CONVERT(varchar(100), DATEADD(day,1,mydate), 111) from dtable
    where datediff(day,CONVERT(varchar(100), DATEADD(day,1,mydate), 111),'@{pipeline().parameters.folders_end_date}')>=0
) 

select concat('inputdata/year=',year(mydate),'/month=',PARSENAME( REPLACE(mydate,'/','.'),2),'/day=',PARSENAME( REPLACE(mydate,'/','.'),1)) as path from dtable option(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

which will give the folder paths array like this:

[image]

Now, pass this array to ForEach and inside ForEach use a Get Meta data activity with parquet dataset. With dataset parameters give `@item().path` in the Get meta data activity to get the Child Items(parquet files).

Here, nested for Each are not supported in ADF currently, so to iterate over the child items I have used another pipeline with **Execute pipeline** activity and passed these child items array to it.

In the child pipeline, append the child items file name to the folder path and generate an array. Join this array with `_` and return the result as string.

[image]

After Execute pipeline activity, I have concatenated the return result with a string variable like below.

[image]

Outside the ForEach, I have converted the **string of paths seperated by `_`** into an array using split and stored in a variable.

**Parent Pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup to get dates structure",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                        "sqlReaderQuery": {
                            "value": ";with dtable as \n(\n    select CONVERT(varchar(100),'@{pipeline().parameters.folders_s_date}', 111) as mydate\nunion all \n    select CONVERT(varchar(100), DATEADD(day,1,mydate), 111) from dtable\n    where datediff(day,CONVERT(varchar(100), DATEADD(day,1,mydate), 111),'@{pipeline().parameters.folders_end_date}')>=0\n) \n\nselect concat('inputdata/year=',year(mydate),'/month=',PARSENAME( REPLACE(mydate,'/','.'),2),'/day=',PARSENAME( REPLACE(mydate,'/','.'),1)) as path from dtable option(MAXRECURSION 0)\n",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        },
                        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                        "partitionOption": "None"
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "SQLdataset",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Itertate through folder paths",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup to get dates structure",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Lookup to get dates structure').output.value",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Get Metadata1",
                            "type": "GetMetadata",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "sourcefiles",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "folderpath": {
                                            "value": "@item().path",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "fieldList": [
                                    "childItems"
                                ],
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "ParquetReadSettings"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Child pipeline for file paths",
                            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "pipeline": {
                                    "referenceName": "child",
                                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                                },
                                "waitOnCompletion": true,
                                "parameters": {
                                    "folderpath": {
                                        "value": "@item().path",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    },
                                    "childitems": {
                                        "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "store return and concat in temp",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Child pipeline for file paths",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "temp",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@concat(variables('paths_string'),'_',activity('Child pipeline for file paths').output.pipelineReturnValue.returns)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "assign temp to path strings",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "store return and concat in temp",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "paths_string",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@variables('temp')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "split paths to array",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Itertate through folder paths",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "final_paths",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@skip(split(variables('paths_string'),'_'),1)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "folders_s_date": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": "2023/04/20"
            },
            "folders_end_date": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": "2023/04/24"
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "final_paths": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "temp": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "paths_string": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

**Child Pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "child",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@pipeline().parameters.childitems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Append variable1",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "child_paths",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@concat(pipeline().parameters.folderpath,'/',item().name)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable1",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "pipelineReturnValue",
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "key": "returns",
                            "value": {
                                "type": "Expression",
                                "content": "@join(variables('child_paths'),'_')"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "setSystemVariable": true
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "folderpath": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "childitems": {
                "type": "array"
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "child_paths": {
                "type": "Array"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

**Paths array:**

[image]

You can pass this array For Each to achieve your requirement.